# How do I get count of people from ExchangeGal sources using ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering()

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, abaddressbooksource

I am trying to get people in three sources (1 MobileMe source and 2* ExchangeGAL sources) of my iOS 4 addressbook. 
The NSLog statement always return 0 people for ExchangeGAL, but returns a count of people for MobileMe. 
After getting all the sources from the iOS address book by using ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook), I am trying to iterate source by source to get more info for each source.

Am I using the ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering correctly?
Would expect a count of all people in the different addressbook sources.

```
-(void)countPeopleInSources
{
    ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
    CFArrayRef allSources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);
    for (CFIndex i = 0; i < CFArrayGetCount(allSources); i++) 
    {
        ABRecordRef source = (ABRecordRef)CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(allSources, i);
        NSNumber *sourceTypeRef = (NSNumber *)((CFNumberRef)ABRecordCopyValue(source, kABSourceTypeProperty));
        ABPersonSortOrdering sortOrdering = ABPersonGetSortOrdering();
        int sourceType = [sourceTypeRef intValue];
        switch (sourceType) {
        case kABSourceTypeCardDAV:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeCardDAV");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeCardDAVSearch:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeCardDAVSearch");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeExchange:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeExchange");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeExchangeGAL:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeExchangeGAL");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeLDAP:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeLDAP");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeLocal:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeLocal");
            break;
        case kABSourceTypeMobileMe:
            NSLog(@"SourceTypeMobileMe"); 
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
        CFArrayRef allPeopleInSource = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(addressBook, source, sortOrdering );
        NSLog(@"Count allPeopleInSource: %i", CFArrayGetCount(allPeopleInSource));

        [sourceTypeRef release];
    }
}
```

EDIT FEB24:
It looks like the code works, but I have a problem getting people count from ExhangeGALs.
Has anyoune successfully retrieved people from ExchangeGAL?
MobileMe source reports back a people count.
Here is the log from Console:

```
2011-02-24 07:04:32.578 Contacts[10099:307] SourceTypeExchangeGAL
2011-02-24 07:04:32.593 Contacts[10099:307] Count allPeopleInSource: 0
2011-02-24 07:04:32.597 Contacts[10099:307] SourceTypeMobileMe
2011-02-24 07:04:32.641 Contacts[10099:307] Count allPeopleInSource: 151
2011-02-24 07:04:32.646 Contacts[10099:307] SourceTypeExchangeGAL
2011-02-24 07:04:32.652 Contacts[10099:307] Count allPeopleInSource: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Using:

```
ABRecordRef sourceWithType (ABSourceType mySourceType)
{
ABAddressBookRef addressBook = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFArrayRef sources = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllSources(addressBook);
CFIndex sourceCount = CFArrayGetCount(sources);
ABRecordRef resultSource = NULL;
for (CFIndex i = 0 ; i < sourceCount; i++) {
    ABRecordRef currentSource = CFArrayGetValueAtIndex(sources, i);
    ABSourceType sourceType = [(NSNumber *)ABRecordCopyValue(currentSource, kABSourceTypeProperty) intValue];
    if (mySourceType == sourceType) {
        resultSource = currentSource;
        break;
    }
}

return resultSource;
}

ABRecordRef localSource()
{
    return sourceWithType(kABSourceTypeLocal);
}

ABRecordRef exchangeSource()
{
     return sourceWithType(kABSourceTypeExchange);
}

ABRecordRef mobileMeSource()
{
     return sourceWithType(kABSourceTypeMobileMe);
}
```

You might find this helpful :[abaddressbook-absource-and-absourcetype](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108413/abaddressbook-absource-and-absourcetype)

Answer (score 2):

Are the people you're expecting to return actually in your addressbook? You shouldn't expect `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering()` to return the entire GAL. That would be massive. You should only expect it to return a subset of `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople()`.