# kABSourceNameProperty returned values

Tags: iphone

In my application i am trying to differentiate contacts from different sources like Exchange,Facebook,Native contacts,`iCloud`.

I used `ABSourceType` to get source type for contacts ,but contacts in different sources
**Ex.** `Yahoo and iCloud` have same source type(value 4) but different source name (yahoo :contacts and iCloud as Card).
I did extensive search to get official Apple Docs to confirm value of `kABSourceNameProperty` for different sources.
Can any one help me in this regard??

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in: [ABAddressBook ABSource and ABSourceType](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108413/abaddressbook-absource-and-absourcetype)

the source type is a simple enum and it isn't possible to differ which "source" creates the Record:

```
enum {
    kABSourceTypeLocal       = 0x0,
    kABSourceTypeExchange    = 0x1,
    kABSourceTypeExchangeGAL = kABSourceTypeExchange | kABSourceTypeSearchableMask,
    kABSourceTypeMobileMe    = 0x2,
    kABSourceTypeLDAP        = 0x3 | kABSourceTypeSearchableMask,
    kABSourceTypeCardDAV     = 0x4,
    kABSourceTypeCardDAVSearch = kABSourceTypeCardDAV | kABSourceTypeSearchableMask,
};
typedef int ABSourceType;
```